# How can I open Outlook Calendar to a 2-3 week view by default?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I use **Outlook 2007**, and I like to view my **calendar 2** (or sometimes 3) **weeks at a time**.  Its relatively easy to do, by dragging my mouse across several weeks in the mini calendar.

**BUT...** it never stays that way.  As soon as I change to Contacts and back to Calendar, the view resets to showing a whole month.

Any ideas about how to change to default view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it cant be done.  Your best option would be choose the one month setting.

You could always go to the [MS Office development blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/) and add it as a feature request.

Comment: this link results in a 404

Answer (score 0):

check out the solution posted in the comments here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2124-outlook-calendar-two-week-view.html

an arcane combination of Alt+ and Ctrl+ keystrokes but it works!

Comment: Please include a relevant quote from that link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unfortunately, but you can easily **`SHIFT+MOUSE_SELECT` or `CTRL+MOUSE_SELECT` the week numbers** of your choice *in the little calendar at the top of the folder pane on the left*.

If you do not want to see weekends, you have to then `CTRL+MOUSE_UNSELECT` the weekend days you wish to hide.

It's annoying and a little cumbersome, but given you only have to do it once in the morning... ;-)